# call expect script from dockerfile exited unexpectedly

Tags: docker, dockerfile, expect, spawn

docker file content:

```
From freeradius/freeradius-server
COPY eccCertImport /
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y expect
RUN ["/bin/sh","/eccCertImport"]

eccCertImport file content:
#!/bin/bash +x
#!/usr/bin/expect
key_passphrase="test123";
set timeout -1
radius_cert_cmd="openssl pkcs12 -in radius_ecc_pfx -clcerts -out radius_ecc_cer -nokeys"
exp_cmd="spawn $radius_cert_cmd;
         expect \"Import Password:\"
         send \"${key_passphrase}\r\"
         interact"
result="$(expect -c "$exp_cmd" |  tee -a a.txt)"
```

when I execute `docker build -t freeradius .`
but I found it fail to execute expect script correctly with a.txt content:

```
root@6384c0a1d92f:/# cat a.txt
spawn openssl pkcs12 -in test.pfx -clcerts -out /etc/freeradius/certs/ecc_radius_cert.pem -nokeys
Enter Import Password:root@6384c0a1d92f:/#
```

while expected results as following:

```
root@f11f33d5e5cd:/# cat a.txt
spawn openssl pkcs12 -in test.pfx -clcerts -out /etc/freeradius/certs/ecc_radius_cert.pem -nokeys
Enter Import Password:
MAC verified OK
root@f11f33d5e5cd:/# exit
```

Comment: What should have happened?

Comment: @glennjackman root@f11f33d5e5cd:/# cat a.txt
spawn openssl pkcs12 -in test.pfx -clcerts -out /etc/freeradius/certs/ecc_radius_cert.pem -nokeys
Enter Import Password:
MAC verified OK
root@f11f33d5e5cd:/# exit

Comment: @glennjackman I also append your concern to my question